# how to add css id in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, filter

I want to add the filters css  I have every time I click on the photos, I want to apply the original photo to the original photo with this ID at any time.

```
            <img src="./assets/img/template.jpg" alt="none" />
          
          none
        
        
          
            <img
              id="grayscale"
              src="./assets/img/template.jpg"
              alt="grayscale"
            />
          
          grayscale
```

---- css
#`grayscale {`
`filter: grayscale(1);`
`}`

`#sepia {`
`filter: sepia(1);`
`}`

`#invert {`
`filter: invert(1);`
`}`

`#blur {`
`filter: blur(2px);`
`}`

`#saturate {`
`filter: saturate(2);`
`}`

`#contrast {`
`filter: contrast(2);`
`}`

`const handleFilter = (e) => {`
`const { target } = e;`
`const { id: filter } = target;`
`// filter: "grayscale" | "sepia" | "invert" | "hue-rotate" | "contrast" | "saturate" | "blur"`

`};`

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. Are you sure you don't want them to be classes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a id in your div

```
document.getElementById('#yourId').style.property = new style
```